# How can i pause dynamically appended videos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I am making a project using `jquery` in which a chat thread has to be created, i am having the following code in my project that pauses all the videos except the one that is playing. This works totally fine until and unless i append a new video in my chat thread.

```
$("video").on("play",function(e)
{
    var $allVideos = $('video');
    $allVideos.not(this).each(function() 
    {
        this.pause();
    });
});
```

For example, i am currently playing a video in a chat thread and i am going to upload another video, while i am on the preview div inside `bootstrap4 modal` that autoplays the video, the one currently playing in the chat thread pauses and the one inside the preview div starts playing automatically. But when i append this preview video in my chat thread and trigger play buttons on this just appened video and the previous video that was paused, they both start playing simultaneously despite of the fact that i am having the code to manage this.

I see i need to pass some selector with on method like
`$("body").on("play","video",function(e){});`
but then i can't use `this` keyword in my code because now it refers to the `body` instead of the `video`.

How do i fix this problem? Thank You In Advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can use `this` in a `.on()` callback and refer to the target `video`. You can also use `e.target`. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Twisty : Thank you for your reply on my question, can you please let me know what exact changes should i made to the part of the code i included in my post. Actually i am somewhat new in this field, so i hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Without a Minimal, Reproducible Example, I would not be able to help.